# SharePoint current user is wrong

Tags: client-object-model

If I logged in as a different user in SharePoint below code doesn't show current user logged in user, what is the problem?

```
Web web = clientContext.Web;
 User user = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser;
 clientContext.Load(web);
 clientContext.Load(user);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
 Console.WriteLine("current user: " + user.LoginName);
```

Answer (score 0):

`clientContext.Web.CurrentUser` will show the user that credentials was used in clientContext object.

Please check which users credentials you are using in clientcontext object.

Comment: it does not showing current user. showing previous user name

Comment: Please tell me how are creating client context object. Are you running this page from sharepoint itselt or some other application

Comment: i have logged in from different user in sharepoint but in code when i checked current user it doesn't show me my current user as logged in user

Comment: Where is your code running that you mentioned? Sharepoint page code behind or some other Application. you can try server object model for this if it is in sharepoint context. this.web.currentuser.

Comment: in visual studio for client object model

Comment: Are you using some form based application/console or creating some application page.

Comment: console application

Comment: In console application it would not reflect current user as per you site. You need to create clientcontext object again with different user credentials. clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");